# R web scraping plotly trace hover text without selenium or phantomjs

Tags: javascript, html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape hover text content from some plotly traces published on the web. I have not performed this type of scraping before and am trying to do this in R without selenium or phantomjs if possible... perhaps using V8? I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. Link to plots are below. Specifically looking for data in plots from Figure 21: Positivity rate for COVID-19 in Alberta by zone. Thanks!

https://www.alberta.ca/stats/covid-19-alberta-statistics.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `rvest` and `jsonlite` the following code will get you the data you are looking for. The data for the plot.ly diagrams is stored in `<script>` tags.

First step is to identify the widget ID of the figure of interest, the code below shows you how to find the widget ID by looking for the caption text of the figure of interest. Then you can search for the correct node with `html_nodes()` and `html_attrs()`. `jsonlite::fromJSON()` converts the JSON data to an R list object.

```r
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)


url <-
  "https://www.alberta.ca/stats/covid-19-alberta-statistics.htm#laboratory-testing"

raw_html <- read_html(url)

# get widget ID

caption <-
  "Figure 21: Positivity rate for COVID-19 in Alberta by zone."

figure_divs <- html_nodes(raw_html, ".figure")

figure_21_div_lgl <- grepl(caption, figure_divs)

widget_id <-
  figure_divs[figure_21_div_lgl] %>%
  html_nodes("div") %>%
  html_attr("id")

# find data for the correct widget_id

data_for <-
  html_nodes(raw_html, "script") %>%
  html_attr("data-for")

data_for_figure_21_lgl <-
  !is.na(data_for) & data_for == widget_id

data_for_figure_21 <-
  html_nodes(raw_html, "script") %>%
  .[data_for_figure_21_lgl] %>%
  html_text()

dff21_l <- fromJSON(data_for_figure_21)
```

In order to extract the data shown in the tooltips (“hover texts”) we need to iterate through the different elements. First extracting the DOM structure with `html_text()`. After that we extract the text with `html_text()`. We iterate through the elements a few more times to split and clean the strings, so that we can finally convert the results into a `data.frame`.

```r
tooltip_text_raw <- unlist(dff21_l$x$data$text)
tooltip_text <- map(tooltip_text_raw, read_html)
tooltip_text <- map(tooltip_text, html_text) %>% unlist()

tooltip_text_split <- strsplit(tooltip_text, "\\:")

tooltip_text_split_almost_clean <-
  map(tooltip_text_split,
      ~ gsub("Report Date|Percent|Number of tests", "", .x))

tooltip_text_split_clean <-
  map(tooltip_text_split_almost_clean, ~ str_squish(.[. != ""]))

tests_df <-
  map_dfr(tooltip_text_split_clean,
          ~ data.frame(
            date = as.Date(.x[1]),
            percent = .x[2],
            tests = .x[3]
          ))

head(tests_df)
#>         date percent tests
#> 1 2020-03-06    9.68    31
#> 2 2020-03-07    0.00   142
#> 3 2020-03-08    0.00   213
#> 4 2020-03-09    2.51   239
#> 5 2020-03-10    3.90   282
#> 6 2020-03-11    1.05   572
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful thank you! I had to change a couple of objects in the first half: asd = raw_html and the name of the widget changed a bit, but I was able to find it. I wonder if the widgets are renamed regularly? Something i'll have to watch out for.

Data export is only for case data by region and I was interested in collecting their testing data. Thanks again.

Comment: I updated my answer to include code that finds the widget ID by the figure caption. If this answers your question please consider accepting my answer as the correct answer.